# How do I run python '__main__' program file from bash prompt in Windows10?

Tags: python, python-3.x, git-bash

I am trying to run a python3 program file and am getting some unexpected behaviors.

I'll start off first with my PATH and env setup configuration. When I run:

`which Python`

I get:

`/c/Program Files/Python36/python`

From there, I `cd` into the directory where my python program is located to prepare to run the program.

Roughly speaking this is how my python program is set up:

```
import modulesNeeded

print('1st debug statement to show program execution')

# variables declared as needed

def aFunctionNeeded():
    print('2nd debug statement to show fxn exe, never prints')
    ... function logic...

if __name__ == '__main__':
    aFunctionNeeded() # Never gets called
```

Here is a link to the repository with the code I am working with in case you would like more details as to the implementation. Keep in mind that API keys are not published, but API keys are in local file correctly:

https://github.com/lopezdp/API.Mashups

My question revolves around why my 1st debug statements inside the files are printing to the terminal, but not the 2nd debug statements inside the functions?

This is happening in both of the `findRestaurant.py` file and the `geocode.py` file.

I know I have written my `if __name__ == '__main__':` program entry point correctly as this is the same exact way I have done it for other programs, but in this case I may be missing something that I am not noticing.

If this is my output when I run my program in my bash terminal:

```
$ python findRestaurant.py
inside geo
inside find
```

then, why does it appear that my `aFunctionNeeded()` method shown in my pseudo code is not being called from the **main**?

Why do both programs seem to fail immediately after the first debug statements are printed to the terminal?

**findRestaurant.py File that can also be found in link above**

```
from geocode import getGeocodeLocation
import json
import httplib2

import sys
import codecs

print('inside find')

sys.stdout = codecs.getwriter('utf8')(sys.stdout)
sys.stderr = codecs.getwriter('utf8')(sys.stderr)

foursquare_client_id = "..."
foursquare_client_secret = "..."


def findARestaurant(mealType,location):
    print('inside findFxn')
    #1. Use getGeocodeLocation to get the latitude and longitude coordinates of the location string.
    latitude, longitude = getGeocodeLocation(location)
    #2.  Use foursquare API to find a nearby restaurant with the latitude, longitude, and mealType strings.
    #HINT: format for url will be something like https://api.foursquare.com/v2/venues/search?client_id=CLIENT_ID&client_secret=CLIENT_SECRET&v=20130815&ll=40.7,-74&query=sushi
    url = ('https://api.foursquare.com/v2/venues/search?client_id=%s&client_secret=%s&v=20130815&ll=%s,%s&query=%s' % (foursquare_client_id, foursquare_client_secret,latitude,longitude,mealType))
    h = httplib2.Http()
    result = json.loads(h.request(url,'GET')[1])

    if result['response']['venues']:
        #3.  Grab the first restaurant
        restaurant = result['response']['venues'][0]
        venue_id = restaurant['id']
        restaurant_name = restaurant['name']
        restaurant_address = restaurant['location']['formattedAddress']
        address = ""
        for i in restaurant_address:
            address += i + " "
        restaurant_address = address
        #4.  Get a  300x300 picture of the restaurant using the venue_id (you can change this by altering the 300x300 value in the URL or replacing it with 'orginal' to get the original picture
        url = ('https://api.foursquare.com/v2/venues/%s/photos?client_id=%s&v=20150603&client_secret=%s' % ((venue_id,foursquare_client_id,foursquare_client_secret)))
        result = json.loads(h.request(url, 'GET')[1])
        #5.  Grab the first image
        if result['response']['photos']['items']:
            firstpic = result['response']['photos']['items'][0]
            prefix = firstpic['prefix']
            suffix = firstpic['suffix']
            imageURL = prefix + "300x300" + suffix
        else:
            #6.  if no image available, insert default image url
            imageURL = "http://pixabay.com/get/8926af5eb597ca51ca4c/1433440765/cheeseburger-34314_1280.png?direct"
        #7.  return a dictionary containing the restaurant name, address, and image url
        restaurantInfo = {'name':restaurant_name, 'address':restaurant_address, 'image':imageURL}
        print ("Restaurant Name: %s" % restaurantInfo['name'])
        print ("Restaurant Address: %s" % restaurantInfo['address'])
        print ("Image: %s \n" % restaurantInfo['image'])
        return restaurantInfo
    else:
        print ("No Restaurants Found for %s" % location)
        return "No Restaurants Found"

if __name__ == '__main__':
    findARestaurant("Pizza", "Tokyo, Japan")
```

**geocode.py File that can also be found in link above**

```
import httplib2
import json

print('inside geo')

def getGeocodeLocation(inputString):
    print('inside of geoFxn')
    # Use Google Maps to convert a location into Latitute/Longitute coordinates
    # FORMAT: https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=1600+Amphitheatre+Parkway,+Mountain+View,+CA&key=API_KEY
    google_api_key = "..."
    locationString = inputString.replace(" ", "+")
    url = ('https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=%s&key=%s' % (locationString, google_api_key))
    h = httplib2.Http()
    result = json.loads(h.request(url,'GET')[1])
    latitude = result['results'][0]['geometry']['location']['lat']
    longitude = result['results'][0]['geometry']['location']['lng']
    return (latitude,longitude)
```

Comment: You could try printing `__name__` to see what it's set to. I haven't looked at this that closely, but if you're running it like `python myprog.py`, `__name__` should be set to `'__main__'`

Comment: You have syntax error in your code example. It cannot be run at all: there is no closing apostrophe in ```print```.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]. We can't debug pseudocode.

Comment: I second @EugenePrimako. You have a syntax error and python fails at runtime just after printing the first line.

Comment: @BryanOakley I provided a link to the exact code if needed

Comment: All print statements have closing parenthesis if you take a look at the link provided to the code repo. I will just copy the code here instead. thanks

Comment: Links to code on another site aren't helpful. If you want help, help us help you by creating a proper [mcve]

Comment: In the linked code, you're rebinding `sys.stdout` and `sys.stderr` immediately after the last `print` statement that works. I suspect the rest of your code *is* working to some degree, you're just not seeing its output. Try removing those lines and you should see some output. I'm not sure if there will be encoding issues or not, but mojibake output is probably better than nothing, at least for debugging.

Comment: @Blckknght thank you for the lead in the right direction and the practicality. I appreciate it.

Comment: @Blckknght it should still output to the console; what he's doing is just changing output encoding. Your code runs well enough on my machine. Now try losing the re-encoding line maybe Windows is not too happy with that.

Comment: @konoufo windows hates it but at least i got a Traceback now! :)

Comment: Cool. Perhaps @Blckknght should rewrite his comment as an answer so you can accept then ?

Comment: Yeah I think ultimately it comes down to how I am calling the google api and I needed to get a traceback so I think his answer is the best considering the circumstances. thanks guys

Comment: Your question would be better if you removed about 90% of the code. Do you really need to call `findARestaurant` nine times in order to duplicate this error?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason you're not seeing the output of the later parts of your code is that you've rebound the standard output and error streams with these lines:

```
sys.stdout = codecs.getwriter('utf8')(sys.stdout)
sys.stderr = codecs.getwriter('utf8')(sys.stderr)
```

I'm not exactly sure why those lines are breaking things for you, perhaps your console does not expect `utf8` encoded output... But because they don't work as intended, you're not seeing anything from the rest of your code, including error messages, since you rebound the `stderr` stream along with the `stdout` stream.